# Finding CDN Tax receipts sent

Tags: advanced-search, searchkit, cdn-tax-receipts

I just ran our receipt job for last year and saw that 13 contributions were marked as ineligible. Unfortunately, unlike an import job, there is no report of what those ineligible contributions are.

I thought I would then do an advanced search and show contributions for which a receipt was not sent. However, the CDN tax receipt extension does not set the receipt sent flag on a contribution -- I do know it's a different kind of receipt to what is meant in CiviCRM.

Then I thought I would generate a list of contacts who had made contributions and compare it to a list of contacts to whom a CDN tax receipt was sent. I then discovered that the CDN tax receipt extension does not create an activity either for creating the receipt or for emailing it to the contact.

How can I determine either:

1. to whom a CDN receipt was sent (or created for)?
2. which contributions were deemed ineligible by CDN Tax Receipt?

Answer (score 1):

Under CiviReport - Contribution Reports, click New Contribution Report. Then there are two templates for receipts issued and not issued.